# Connection::SQLGetInfoW: [Simba][ODBC] (11180) SQLGetInfo property not found: 1750

Tags: google-bigquery

This is a setup where Microsoft's Power BI is the frontend for the data presentation to end-users. Behind it there's an on-premises PBI gateway which connects to BigQuery via Magnitude Simba ODBC driver for BigQuery. Since two days ago, after always working flawlessly, the PBI data refresh started failing due to timeout.
BigQuery ODBC driver's debug shows these two errors below in hundreds of rows per refresh:

SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_connection_9.log:Aug 29 15:21:54.154 ERROR 544 Connection::SQLGetInfoW: [Simba][ODBC] (11180) SQLGetInfo property not found: 180
SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_connection_9.log:Aug 29 15:22:49.427 ERROR 8176 Connection::SQLGetInfoW: [Simba][ODBC] (11180) SQLGetInfo property not found: 1750

And only occurence per refresh of this:

SimbaODBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery_connection_6.log:Aug 29 16:56:15.102 ERROR 6704 BigQueryAPIClient::GetResponseCheckErrors: HTTP error: Error encountered during execution. Retrying may solve the problem.

After some intensive research web search, it kinda looks like this might be related to 'wrong' coding, either wrong data types or strings that are too big, but nothing conclusive.

Other, smaller, refreshes to the same place work without issues.

Do we have any knowledgebase or reference for such cryptic error messages? Any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Already tried:

- Searching Google;
- Updating Magnitude Simba ODBC driver for BigQuery to the latest
  version;
- Updating PBI Gateway to the latest version;
- Rebooting the gateway server.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when ODBC drivers try to pull the data in streams which is via port 444. You either need to enable port 444 for optimal performance or disable streams, so that the data is pulled using pagination(Not recommended for huge data).

[image]